# I'm starting a new job in 20 days - can I include my future income when applying for a credit card now?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, credit-score, income

I'm starting a new job soon and moving to a new city. I've never held a credit card and want to apply for one. As with all moves there are likely to be expenses so I'd love to be able to stick them on my credit card to start taking advantage of the cashback (obviously wouldn't use more than I can pay back once my new salary kicks in).

When applying for a card I am asked to report my employment status and income. Right at this very moment I'm not in employment as I was taking some time to travel between jobs. I'm due to start working towards the end of this month - I have a written offer which I have accepted and returned signed. Is it ok to report my future income instead or would that be considered fraud?

Comment: It's a good question.  What first leaps to my mind is "don't count your chickens before they hatch".

Comment: Past tax return, current paystub, and formal offer of employment (that has been accepted) are all suitable as proof of income.

Comment: Why not just wait until you start the new job before applying for the credit card? Is there some reason why you need to get this card now and can't wait 3 weeks?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: But when does a credit card issuer ever ask for proof of income?

Comment: `"As with all moves there are likely to be expenses so I'd love to be able to stick them on my credit card to start taking advantage of the cashback..."`

Comment: @jamesqf: It seems pretty rare that they ask to actually see the proof... but if you only make claims that are provable, it cannot be called fraud.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: But it's not fraud, since s/he stating what the income will be whe s/he has the card.  Look at it the other way round, and suppose last year's tax return showed $100K income, but s/he's unemployed this year.  Would it be ok to use that tax return to support a claim of income?

Comment: @jamesqf: I agree it's not fraud, that's what I said.  As for using past tax returns, one needs to be truthful about whatever the actual question on the application is, which means if you've left a stellar career to take a vow of poverty it would be inappropriate to refer to income from that past career, but in the case of someone between jobs but seeking to have similar work, past tax returns / paystubs do prove earning potential.

Answer (score 4):

If you are between jobs and had a job a month before and you are sure that you have the employment letter, then it should be fine. I guess intend of the question is "can you pay( **earning potential** ) ". Letter of the question is in question.