# is it required to give exact /approximate or rounded income for credit card

Tags: united-states, credit-card, income

A friend of mine is self employed for personal and self-employment(Doing business as), and at looking at [I'm starting a new job in 20 days - can I include my future income when applying for a credit card now?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110922) I remember he told me that He approximate ( conservatively, so if income in pas year has been on average 85k), he give out $75K as his annual income. He has both personal and business credit card and pays on time.

My question is, s that OK or not OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly find to approximate. A CC issuer won't ask for verification often, and even if so, they won't balk over a couple thousand or ten even. If you're 50k+ more off what you actually made, however, you may run into issues and they may close your account(s) due to deceiving them. It's hard for a risk averse organization to continue trusting someone who blatantly lied to them.

Comment: But if we give exact, banks has too much of our information. Should not they give an option where we can say, that my income is atleast X amount. so even if someone has income at 150K or 1M or 100M, if the requirement of the credit card can be satisfied with 70K, why should not one just say atleast 75K

Comment: But they're not requiring exact information, which is why they don't balk if your income is off by a few thousand dollars. TBH, I'm surprised they don't require income verification for credit in excess of $X.